# Jenkins failed to find target android-19

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

Try to build Android project using Jenkins and endure failure!
Every time I receive an error:

```
17:59:34.126 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
17:59:34.126 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:packageDebug'.
17:59:34.126 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > failed to find target android-19
```

BUT! Android 19 I have installed.

```
MBP-ZK:~ tahorg$ echo $ANDROID_HOME 
/Applications/androidsdk
```

In Jenkins:

[image]

Folders with SDKs

```
MBP-ZK:platforms tahorg$ ls -la /Applications/androidsdk/platforms/
total 0
drwxrwxrwx@ 16 tahorg  admin  544 12 май 16:31 .
drwxrwxr-x@ 13 tahorg  admin  442 19 май 16:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x  11 tahorg  admin  374 12 май 16:29 android-10
drwxr-xr-x  12 tahorg  admin  408 29 апр 17:01 android-11
drwxr-xr-x  12 tahorg  admin  408 29 апр 16:58 android-12
drwxr-xr-x  12 tahorg  admin  408 29 апр 16:55 android-13
drwxr-xr-x  10 tahorg  admin  340 29 апр 16:52 android-14
drwxr-xr-x  10 tahorg  admin  340 29 апр 16:50 android-15
drwxr-xr-x  11 tahorg  admin  374 29 апр 16:48 android-16
drwxr-xr-x  11 tahorg  admin  374 29 апр 16:46 android-17
drwxr-xr-x  11 tahorg  admin  374 29 апр 16:43 android-18
drwxrwxrwx@ 11 tahorg  admin  374 22 фев 00:11 android-19
drwxr-xr-x  14 tahorg  admin  476 29 апр 17:06 android-3
drwxr-xr-x  14 tahorg  admin  476 29 апр 17:05 android-4
drwxr-xr-x  11 tahorg  admin  374 12 май 16:31 android-7
drwxr-xr-x  11 tahorg  admin  374 12 май 16:30 android-8
```

And list of targets:

```
MBP-ZK:workspace tahorg$ android list target | grep android-19
id: 14 or "android-19"
```

Part of app build.gradle (not parent build.gradle)

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same problem. Build works fine in Android Studio or using Gradle on the command line, but fails on Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

Double check the permissions on the SDK folder (and the folders above it). I had the SDK folder in my own users home folder, so the jenkins user had no permission to read it. Although the `/Applications` folder you're using should work, maybe this answer helps someone else with the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Anyone else still looking for this answer, I had to add +x permission to everything in the SDK directory.

Before adding +x, I had moved the whole thing from my Home to a Shared directory and given everything a +r, but these two changes alone didn't work.

Comment: Changing the permission of the sdk folder worked for me too: 
`chmod -R +rx ~/android-sdk`

Answer (score 0):

All sub packages are installed?
You can use SDK manager from command line if you need:
http://tools.android.com/recent/updatingsdkfromcommand-line

Comment: All sub packages are installed